# Openlayer, how to trigger translate without click

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to implement something like this sample https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/translate-features.html

but instead of clicking on feature then dragging, I already have target feature and I want to trigger translate event on it. When the event triggered, the feature is moved under mouse cursor and when left-clicking on map, the feature is transferred to that position.

Can openlayers do something like that or I have to custom the translate?

Comment: The interaction relies on pointerdown and pointerdrag events, so you will probably need to simulate those as in the OpenLayers tests  https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/test/browser/spec/ol/interaction/translate.test.js#L68  A real click will be followed by a pointerup event which will end the interaction https://codesandbox.io/s/translate-features-forked-b0f0m

Comment: @Mike thank you very much, it's clear for me. Replacing x, y in `simulateEvent` with pixel on target feature will give what I want in this question. If you don't mind, you can post your comment as answer that I could accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction relies on `pointerdown` and `pointerdrag` events, so you will probably need to simulate those as in the OpenLayers tests https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/test/browser/spec/ol/interaction/translate.test.js#L68  A real click will be followed by a `pointerup` event which will end the interaction https://codesandbox.io/s/translate-features-forked-b0f0m